# Hi, Im new to magento 2 What is this condition action to?

Tags: magento2

[image]

Im not sure what is this function doing.
Whats the action like ? what if i set to 1 or 0 or 2

Answer (score 0):

`Condition Action` means, when the above `condition` set by you into this section are fulfill then and then above rule is work.